# Android:Copy database in assets folder null pointer exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I have read almost all the topics related to my problem in here so please do not say it is duplicate or has been questioned before.

I created the tables and the database in Sqlite Expert Personal 3. I copied it in assets folder. Right now I want to tell the android to check if there isnt already a database, copy the database from assets folder. so I do this:

```
datasource = new DataSource(this);
    List<Prayer> prayers = datasource.findAllPrayers();

    if (prayers.size == 0)
    {
        dbopenhelper.copyDataBase();
    }
    datasource.open();
```

Here it should check if there is any row at the table "prayers" and if there wasn't any rows, it should copy the database. but when I run the program, I get nullPointerException.

---

And here is my OpenHelper class:

```
package org.bihe.database;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String LOGTAG = "PRAYERBOOK_APP";
    //
    private static Context context;
    //
    private static String DB_PATH;
    //
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Prayers.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // ***Tables***
    public static final String TABLE_PRAYERTOPIC = "prayertopic";
    public static final String TABLE_PRAYER = "prayer";
    public static final String TABLE_FAVORITES = "favorites";
    public static final String TABLE_PRAYEROFTOPIC = "prayeroftopic";
    public static final String TABLE_FAVORITEPRAYERS = "favoriteprayers";
    public static final String TABLE_AUDIOPRAYERS = "audioprayers";
    // ***Table prayertopic columns***
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_ID = "prayertopic_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_NAME = "prayertopic_name";
    // ***Table prayer columns***
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYER_ID = "prayer_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYER_NAME = "prayer_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYER = "prayer";
    // ***Table favorites columns***
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITE_ID = "favorite_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITE_NAME = "favorite_name";
    // ***Table prayeroftopic columns***
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYEROFTOPIC_ID = "prayeroftopic_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYER_ID_POT = "prayer_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_ID_POT = "prayertopic_ID";
    // ***Table favoriteprayer columns***
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITEPRAYER_ID = "favoriteprayer_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVORITE_ID_FP = "favorite_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRAYER_ID_FP = "prayer_ID";
    // ***Table auidioprayers***
    public static final String COLUMN_AUDIOPRAYER_ID = "audioprayer_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUDIOPRAYER_NAME = "audioprayer_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUDIOPRAYER_ADDRESS = "audioprayer_address";

    // ***Creating Tables***
    private static final String CREATE_PRAYER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_PRAYER + " (" + COLUMN_PRAYER_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_PRAYER_NAME
            + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PRAYER + " TEXT " + ")";
    //
    private static final String CREATE_PRAYERTOPIC_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_PRAYERTOPIC + " (" + COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_NAME
            + " TEXT" + ")";
    //
    private static final String CREATE_PRAYEROFTOPIC_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_PRAYEROFTOPIC + " (" + COLUMN_PRAYEROFTOPIC_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " FOREIGN KEY("
            + COLUMN_PRAYER_ID_POT + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_PRAYER + "("
            + COLUMN_PRAYER_ID + ") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE "
            + " FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_ID_POT + ") REFERENCES "
            + TABLE_PRAYERTOPIC + "(" + COLUMN_PRAYERTOPIC_ID
            + ") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE " + ") ";

    public DBOpenHelper(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        context = ctx;
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
    }

    //
    public static void copyDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH
                    + DATABASE_NAME);
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int buffer;
            while ((buffer = input.read(data)) != -1)
            {
                output.write(data, 0, buffer);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error in copying database...");
        }
    }

    //

    // ***--***
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRAYER_TABLE);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Table has been created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRAYER);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong with my code. THANKS IN ADVANCE

---

Edit:

```
    02-21 20:06:17.346: E/Trace(4814): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-21 20:06:17.896: I/PRAYERBOOK_APP(4814): Database opened
02-21 20:06:17.968: I/PRAYERBOOK_APP(4814): Database opened
02-21 20:06:18.278: D/libEGL(4814): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
02-21 20:06:18.430: D/(4814): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a13b0b8, tid 4814
02-21 20:06:19.047: D/libEGL(4814): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
02-21 20:06:19.057: D/libEGL(4814): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
02-21 20:06:20.127: W/EGL_emulation(4814): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-21 20:06:20.169: D/OpenGLRenderer(4814): Enabling debug mode 0
02-21 20:06:20.507: D/dalvikvm(4814): GC_CONCURRENT freed 84K, 7% free 2706K/2908K, paused 91ms+6ms, total 199ms
02-21 20:06:56.497: I/PRAYERBOOK_APP(4814): Database closed
02-21 20:06:57.127: D/dalvikvm(4814): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 6% free 2992K/3180K, paused 35ms, total 52ms
02-21 20:06:57.137: I/dalvikvm-heap(4814): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.110MB for 1127536-byte allocation
02-21 20:06:57.217: D/dalvikvm(4814): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 4090K/4284K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
02-21 20:06:57.347: D/dalvikvm(4814): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 5% free 4086K/4284K, paused 27ms+32ms, total 134ms
02-21 20:06:57.457: D/AndroidRuntime(4814): Shutting down VM
02-21 20:06:57.457: W/dalvikvm(4814): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.bihe.prayerbookletapp/org.bihe.prayerbookletapp.ExpListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at org.bihe.database.DataSource.findAllPrayers(DataSource.java:163)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at org.bihe.prayerbookletapp.ExpListActivity.onCreate(ExpListActivity.java:65)
02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at
```

android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     ... 11 more

---

and here :  02-21 20:06:57.477: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at org.bihe.database.DataSource.findAllPrayers(DataSource.java:163)

it refers to my findAllPrayers() method in Datasource class:

```
Here is my findAllPrayers() method which is in datasource class:

public List<Prayer> findAllPrayers()
{

    List<Prayer> prayerlist = new ArrayList<Prayer>();
    //
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_PRAYER,
            allPrayerColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    //
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Child Cursor returned " + cursor.getCount() + " row(s).");

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {

            Prayer p = new Prayer();
            p.setPrayer_name(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PRAYER_NAME)));

            p.setPrayer_ID(cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PRAYER_ID)));
            p.setPrayer(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBOpenHelper.COLUMN_PRAYER)));

            prayerlist.add(p);
        }
    }

    return prayerlist;

}
```

Comment: I strongly encourage you to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), as opposed to your existing code, which will fail on millions of devices, since you elected to hard-code a path to internal storage. Beyond that, please edit your question and post your Java stack trace, along with details of what lines in the stack trace correspond to what lines in your source code shown in your question.

Comment: I edited as you said and I'm ganna look at SqliteAssetHelper as you said right now and thank you. I hope you can figure out what is wrong :(

Comment: What specific line in `DataSource.java` is line 163?

Comment: this line:  'Cursor cursor = database.query(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_PRAYER,
            allPrayerColumns, null, null, null, null, null);'

Comment: Then `database` is `null`.

Comment: Why is it null? It shouldn't be null because I Created the database tables in onCreate method of DBOpenHelper Class.

Comment: "Why is it null?" -- I have no idea, since your code declaring and assigning a value to `database` does not exist in the question AFAICT. "I Created the database tables in onCreate method of DBOpenHelper Class" -- so? That creates database tables. It does not assign a value to a `database` data member of `DataSource`.

Comment: I still don't know what to do to solve this problem but thank you So much. Thanks a lot :)